# taskkill процессов с одинаковым именем но разным pid

Tags: windows, cmd

Допустим я открываю несколько экземпляров командной строки и запускаю bat файл командной строкой который должен закрыть все экземпляры командной строки кроме своего. Все экземпляры имеют одинаковые имена `cmd.exe` но разные PID, как мне в bat файле такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe"
```

Для каждого PID во второй строке Вы получите полное имя окна - т.е. включая и текущую выполняемую команду. Вот на неё и ориентируйтесь...

Comment: Как ориентироваться? Программа будет работать на разных компьютерах и заранее сколько экземпляров и под какими PID будут открыты и будут ли вообще открыты. Нужно закрыть всё кроме текущего.

Comment: Простите, а Вы выполнили указанную команду? Обратили внимание, что только у неё в имени окна есть текст этой самой команды? Или Вы полагаете, что все копии одновременно будут выполнять получение списка? слишком маловероятно...

Comment: Да, так а как мне закрыть все экземпляры кроме текущего? Я не понимаю.

Comment: Парсите первую строку, вынимаете оттуда PID в переменную среды. Парсите вторую на предмет наличия указанной команды, если найдено - выходите из цикла парсинга, иначе парсите следующую пару. А затем киляете все PID, кроме того, что в переменной.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста в ответе так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Выполняется одной командой taskkill, "прибить" все процессы cmd.exe, в которых не исполняется команда taskkill:

```
taskkill /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /fi "Windowtitle ne C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - taskkill*"
```

Данная команда предполагает, что командная строка вызывается стандартным способом и её интерпретатор находится по пути "c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

Comment: нажмите на кнопку "править" и перенесите замечание из комментария в основное тело ответа.